# Rails session is blank when using HTTP put

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I have a situation, where one particular link is resulting in an empty session hash.
This is not good as I need to find a model by using the session_id.

The link that is causing trouble is:

```
<div id="marker_images">
  <% @marker_image_urls.each do |image_url| %>
    <%= link_to( image_url, 
                 location_type_path(@location_type.id, 
                 :location_type => {:preset_marker_url => image_url}), 
                 :method => :put,
                 :remote => true ) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and the code that finds the model from the session id (which is called using a before_filter):

```
def get_organisation
  @organisation = Organisation.find_by_session_id(session[:session_id])
end
```

In debugger mode, `session` == `{}`

If I change the link_to to be a HTTP 'get' instead of 'put', the session is sent.
However, this request isn't appropriate for a 'get' as it is modifying data.

Why would 'get' include the session, but 'put' not?

Comment: I think you have to give some more information. Only this link_to method is not sufficient.

Comment: I added the info about get vs put. What other info would help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, found it.
Because the link is a http-put, rails does not automatically include the authenticity token, as it does with an http-get. So, by passing the authenticity token as a param, rails recognises the session.

```
<div id="marker_images">
  <% @marker_image_urls.each do |image_url| %>
    <%= link_to( image_tag(image_url), 
                 location_type_path(@location_type.id, 
                                    :location_type => {:preset_marker_url => image_url},
                                    :authenticity_token => form_authenticity_token), 
                 :method => :put,
                 :remote => true ) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This page helped me out in stumbling upon this solution: http://www.kolodvor.net/2010/01/02/rails-csrf-and-ajax-requests/

Comment: Got the same problem. The rails.js (jquery) file didn't include the token in every instance that it should, which caused some problems. https://gist.github.com/865699

Comment: Do we have to pass the authenticity_token in addition to the X-CSRF-Token?

Comment: The link to the kolodvor site is broken.

Answer (score 1):

It happens if you forgot to add `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` to your layout. Add it like

```
<head>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the CSRF protection in Rails. See [this security patch notification](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails)

To permanently fix this issue, follow the instructions on the above link. The latest versions of rails.js have been patched to add the authenticity_token parameter to all AJAX requests generated by Rails.

If you are upgrading an early version of Rails, you may need to include `csrf_meta_tag` in your layout as suggested by Vikrant Chaudhary.